# Java-What is the best way to check if a string contain alphanumeric characters or not

Tags: java

I am new to regular expression, can any one tell me what is the best option to check if a string is containing only alphanumeric characters and why?
`value.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");`   or `value.matches("\\w+");`

Comment: What means *best option* ? Best in what?

Comment: `\w` is just a predefined character class, the same as writing `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` so your both regex are not really the same, but the the difference has nothing to do with your question I guess

Comment: @Jens by "best" i mean which is more appropriate and which will you prefer out of both and why ?

Comment: i would prefer a mix of both: `value.matches("^\\w+$");`

Comment: Most appropriate?  Please specify your criteria for "appropriateness".  (And try to give an objective, non-circular specification.)   Asking for which we prefer is asking for an opinion, and Questions that ask for opinion-based answers are off-topic.

Comment: define alphanumeric at first

Comment: @xander : so if I write ("^[a-zA-Z_0-9]*$") and I have other "\w " then will it be still the same or the "start and end" condition will make some difference in the first case here?

Comment: Hint: look up the definitions in the javadocs for the `Pattern` class, and you make up your mind which is *correct* for what you are actually trying to achieve.  Like ... depending on what do *you* mean by alphanumeric ...

Comment: @Gaurav the start and end makers make a difference of course, but as I said `\w` is just `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` in short. but "\\w+" will match a string like "  ab12%&" because it contains `\w`, so you needd to use "^\\w+$" as @Jens said to check the whole string. Just remember if you leave `^` and `$` out it essentially is a contains check.

Comment: @xander Thanks for the answer, now got the difference. Actually I wanted a string which can have all the alphanumeric characters except punctuation so here what I am going to use is.Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
        if(value.matches("^\\w+$") && !m.find()){
         return true;
        }

Comment: @Gaurav ok but if `value.matches("^\\w+$")` returns true it can never contain any punctuation characters in the first place. So it's unnecessary or I don't get it.

Comment: @xander yes you are right, I checked it just now. Thank you again.